# How to install downloaded BlogEngine.Net Theme?

Tags: themes, blogengine.net

I have downloaded a new theme from web to use it for my locally hosted blogengine website. I want to use this theme.

I tried extracting the downloaded theme and putting it into `..\MyBlog\themes` folder. It still does not show up as available theme in BlogEngines themes setting tab:
[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you copy the files to `themes` folder, you need logout and login again.

Answer (score 4):

**Make sure you have the "Read Only"  button unchecked.**

Pull it up through the folder and not through Visual Studio.  Right click on it and view
the "Properties"  Make sure that the "Read Only" button is unchecked.

If it is checked uncheck it and apply to all folders and sub folders.

That should do it.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the following steps to get the themes in the "theme" section of the "Customize" tab:

1. Download a theme from any website and extract the theme in a folder.
2. Copy the folder in the "**themes**" folder of the "**BlogEngine(web)**" folder.
3. Now go to the administration section and **log off**.
4. **Log In** again to get the themes available in the "Installed" category.

It is possible that you might get several errors like "**.master.cs**" not found.
To fix such bugs, go to the "**theme_name**" folder --> **content** --> **themes** --> **theme_name**, and copy all the files and folders and paste them in the "theme_name" folder.

The errors would be generally due to improper paths of files and images.
It is also possible that you might get pages that donot have images or pages without CSS properties.

Implementing the above steps would fix all of them.

-Tushar Sharma

Answer (score 1):

If BlogEngine.net is hosted as an Azure Website, the site must be stopped and started for newly added themes to show up in the list of available themes.